# translate webpage automatically in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

is there a way I can automatically translate my page according to the location of the visitor. because of google translator no longer for free.

I appreciate any sample and idea

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use i18n js to translate and geocode the users location params (available in the browser through the `navigator.geolocation`)

Documentation links :
https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/getCurrentPosition

https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js